# Google Maps - Places API to return multiple results with markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Is there any way I can do the following with the Google Places API?

- Search for multiple places (Nike store + Mcdonalds) and place them on a map with custom icon markers for each result? I.e.: Nike symbol for the Nike store and Mcdonalds "m" symbol for the Mcdonald's stores? Like this..

[Quick example image](http://oi57.tinypic.com/rwl6v4.jpg) - can't upload here as I don't have enough reputation.

I have tried to do a multiple places search with maps.google.com however the most it will take by using a pipeline in between is a maximum of 2 places.

Can anyone share an example here or jsfiddle of how I could go about the above with the custom icon markers?

I can't see any documentation on this.

Thank you.

//Multiple locations
I have no issue getting this working when I'm using lat,lng passed in as a data array, but I'm unsure how to do the two things above - putting in 2 places in the array (without lat,lng) and having different custom marker icons for each of those 2 places results. Each place should output 100+ results and be plotted up on the map.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

  setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

//I need to do this for Places by inputting Place names in the array like "Nike", "Mcdonalds" where I don't have all the latitude and longitudes for every result.. yet
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map (wondering how I can set different marker icons for each Places data set in the array above?
  var image = {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  var shape = {
      coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Post what you've tried so that people can help you on it.

Comment: Thanks @Xlander I'll do that now.

Comment: What is the client supposed to type in the search input?  An address, or the the name of the shop?  Do you have a list of the shops you are interested in (You could start making/collecting icons of the logos)?

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay I actually want to hardcode 2 places - Nike and McDonald's. It's for a mashup without any client input. Already have the logos :) looking for some guidance as to how to do the places API as per my question. In my example http://oi57.tinypic.com/rwl6v4.jpg I'd like to display that for every matching result. Thanks